# Can an algebraic product be written in terms of sums?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For these types of algebra problems, I just don't see a strict "impossibility" theorem, or maybe I would if I knew Galois theory.

For this, I have two variables, $x = \tfrac{1}{2}u - \tfrac{1}{2}v + \tfrac{1}{2}u - \tfrac{1}{2}t$
and another variable $y = \frac{\sqrt{v}}{\sqrt{u}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{u}}.$

Now, I take note that of the many possibilities, there's two sums in $x,$ $A_1 = \tfrac{1}{2}u - \tfrac{1}{2}v$ and $A_2 = \frac{1}{2}u - \frac{1}{2}t$ and thus $x = A_1 + A_2.$

What I'm interested in knowing is whether $y$ can be written *strictly* in terms of the sums $A_1$ and $A_2.$

In playing around with the formulas, I arrive at $\frac{\sqrt{-2A_1 + u} \cdot \sqrt{-2A_2 + u}}{u}$ and where I get stuck is writing $u$ in terms of $A_1$ and $A_2.$

At this stage, how do I know it's "impossible" that some kind of whacky intricate algebraic function of $y$ can't completely get rid of $u$ and leave an expression containing only $A_1$ and $A_2$?

Answer (score 1):

If you add some constant to $u$, $v$ and $t$ then $A_1$ and $A_2$ don't change, but $y$ (in general) does. So $y$ can't be expressed in terms of $A_1$ and $A_2$.

Take, for example, $u = v = 1$, $t = 2$. Corresponding $A_1 = 0$, $A_2 = -\frac{1}{2}$ and $y = \sqrt{2}$.

Now, take $u' = v' = 2$, $t' = 3$. Corresponding $A'_1 = 0$, $A'_2 = -\frac{1}{2}$ and $y' = \sqrt\frac 32$.

As we have $A_1 = A'_1$ and $A_2 = A'_2$ but $y \neq y'$, $y$ can't be expressed in terms of $A_1$ and $A_2$.

Comment: Why does this situation where two isolated examples of $y$ changing but $A_1$ and $A_2$ not, imply impossibility?

Comment: Because if we have expression $y = f(A_1, A_2)$ then $y' = f(A'_1, A'_2)$ (for the same $f$), but as $A_1 = A'_1$ and $A_2 = A'_2$ then $f(A_1, A_2) = f(A'_1, A'_2)$ that implies $y = y'$, but we have $y \neq y'$.